Problem with stored procedure that not save my rows
I do a stored procedue in my db, I have more of 1 row if I run stored procedure in mysql workbench, but if I try to debug my programm result set is empty
I tried debug, but rs is empty. This is my stored procedure:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getIntervento`(
    IN in_stato TINYINT(1)
     )
     BEGIN
     DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE numero INT;
     DECLARE modello VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE marca VARCHAR(45);
     DECLARE costo INT;
     DECLARE descrizioneComp VARCHAR(45);
    
     DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT i.`numeroRiparazione` ,i.`marca`,i.`modello`, i.`costo`, c.`descrizione` 
        FROM `intervento` i JOIN `necessita` n on i.numeroRiparazione=n.codiceIntervento 
        JOIN `componente` c ON n.codiceComponente=c.codice
        WHERE pagamento=in_stato;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `cercaIntervento`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `cercaIntervento` (
        `numero` INT,
        `marca`VARCHAR(45),
        `modello` VARCHAR(45),
        `costo` INT,
        `descrizione` VARCHAR(45)
    );
    SET transaction isolation level read committed;
    START transaction;
    OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO numero, marca, modello, costo,descrizioneComp;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO `cercaIntervento` VALUES (numero, marca, modello, costo, descrizioneComp);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT * FROM `cercaIntervento`;
   COMMIT;
   END,

this is my java code:
public List<Intervento> viewIntervento(int n) throws SQLException {
        Intervento intervento;
        List<Intervento> allIntervento = new ArrayList<>();
        try(CallableStatement cs = connection.conn.prepareCall("{call getIntervento(?)}")){
            cs.setInt(1,n);
            boolean status=cs.execute();
            if(status){
                ResultSet rs=cs.getResultSet();
                while(rs.next()){
                    int numero=rs.getInt(1);
                    String marca = rs.getString(2);
                    String modello = rs.getString(3);
                    int costo = rs.getInt(4);
                    String descrizione = rs.getString(5);

                    intervento = new Intervento(marca, modello, costo, descrizione, numero);
                    allIntervento.add(intervento);
                }
                }


            }catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException("errore durante la lettura: " + e.getMessage());

          }
           return allIntervento;
      }


Not sure if there's enough information to help, but is pagamento a primary key, for a single record? ... How may records are found with the select for the cursor?

Are you connecting to the correct database from your Java / JDBC program?

Why do you even have a loop in your procedure? it looks like you just want a simple select? Why procedure at all to be honest

primary key isn't pagamento, i Have a code AI in my table, in my query on benchmark returns more than a row, the loop is for save the rows on the temporary table. If I run my programm, the rs is empty whit the same parameter that I use with my benchmark

yes the db is correct beacuase the rest of my programm it's consistent with the other stored procedure

I fix it, thaks to all
